# Using ffmpeg to record podcast, each audio source in a channel

Tags: arch-linux, pulseaudio, ffmpeg

I'm recording a podcast and need to record the audio using one side of the stereo track with my mic audio and the other side with the audio coming from the internet. Any tips? Have `ffmpeg` in my box and uses Arch Linux 64

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with the [amerge filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amerge-1):

```
$ ffmpeg -i left.mp3 -i right.mp3 -filter_complex amerge stereo.mp3
```

Assuming the input files are mono, `amerge` will automatically create stereo output. I should note, however, that podcasts are mono so they can be consumed with just one earbud. The stereo effect sounds interesting since it puts you in the middle of the conversation, which is kinda neat, but I've never heard it on an actual podcast. To make the output mono, set the audio channels to 1 with the `-ac 1` option.